# Trying to select multiple list items for y-axis data; getting TypeError "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python, list, bar-chart, typeerror

I am trying to use different numbers from the list 'increases' for different y-axis data, however I get the error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'. I saw that someone said to use np.asarray(), however, this gave the error 'too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 7 were indexed'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numbers_ci = [1.113, 1.068, 0.999, 1.021, 1.078, 1.086, 1.024, 1.025, 1.082, 1.215, 1.069, 1.09, 1.11, 1.106, 1.02, 1.087, 1.124, 1.069, 1.004, 1.002, 1.058, 0.993, 1.024, 0.926, 1.099, 1.083, 0.995, 1.023, 1.422]

def calculate_concentration(numbers):
    concentrations = [0.2957 - (number/2.185*0.3722) for number in numbers]
    
    increases = [(concentration - concentrations[-1])/concentrations[-1]*100 for concentration in concentrations]
    
    print(f"The average absorbance numbers are:\n{numbers}")
    print(f"The concentrations of bound copper are:\n{concentrations}")
    print(f"The increases in copper binding are:\n{increases}")
    
    reactions = ["KNO3", "NH4NO3", "(NH4)2S2O8", "(NH4)2Cr2O7", "H2O2", "H2SO4", "NaIO4"]
    x = np.arange(len(reactions))
    # y1 = increases[1,5,9,13,17,21,25]
    # y2 = increases[2,6,10,14,18,22,26]
    # y3 = increases[3,7,11,15,19,23,27]
    # y4 = increases[4,8,12,16,20,25,28]
    y1 = [98.4, 109.6, 108.3, 99.4, 94.9, 116.0, 102.9]
    y2 = [112.8, 107, 65.9, 100.7, 112.5, 136.7, 108]
    y3 = [134.8, 126.8, 112.5, 128.1, 133.2, 126.8, 136]
    y4 = [127.7, 126.5, 105.8, 106.7, 133.8, 158, 127.1]
    width = 0.2
    
    plt.bar(x-0.3, y1, width, color="blue", label="oxidator")
    plt.bar(x-0.1, y2, width, color="cyan", label="KCN")
    plt.bar(x+0.1, y3, width, color="orange", label="KFe")
    plt.bar(x+0.3, y4, width, color="red", label="KHex")
    plt.xticks(x, reactions, fontsize=7, rotation=45)    
    plt.xlabel("Reactions")
    plt.ylabel("Increase in binding capacity (%)")
    plt.title("Pure chitin")
    plt.legend(fontsize=7)
    plt.show()

calculate_concentration(numbers_ci)
```

As you can see, I put # in front of the way I would like to do it. If I write the numbers into a list manually, I get the correct figure, but this takes a lot of time and I have more data I need to do this for. The question is, how can I correctly use list indices to get the right numbers in the different bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to access the value at index `1,5,9,13...` in the list `increases`, and put the values in a separate list. `increases[1,5,9,13,17,21,25]` is not a supported way to do this, you can only access one index at the time.

```
y1 = [increases[i] for i in [1,5,9,13,17,21,25]]
```